# Rspec 3 stub class variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rabbitmq, rspec3, bunny

anybody know, how I can stub class variable initialization?

I define

```
@@connection = Bunny.new.start
```

for restrict connection numbers, but now I have to test it, and when I try stub it in general way, like

```
allow_any_instance_of(Bunny).to receive(:start) { something }
```

it doesn't work. `@@` variable initializes earlier.

Also, I can redefine it:

```
before do
  @@connection = double('conn')
end
```

but it doesn't suit for me because I have to do not allow create a connection to AMQP

**SOLVE**

I didn't figure out how to do that, so I used bunny-mock, and it helped me

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20518845/259889

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't what I need. I need stub class variable during initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's bad practice but what about:

```
YourClass.class_variable_set(:@@variable, 'value')
```

i. e.

```
before do
 YourController.class_variable_set(:@@connection, 'value')
end
```